# Java - user interface and termination

Tags: java, interface

For a project I need two wirte a java program with a user interface. Not GUI. Only a user interface asking the user to enter a command. The user should also be able to terminate the program. Do someone maybe have a link to a website that might help - I'm not sure in which direction to look...

Comment: So do you want a [command-line interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a tutorial but here's a basic example of what you describe to get you started. My app here takes two commands 'hello' which prints a greeting, and 'quit' which exits the program. Any other input will display 'unknown command'.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String command;
            do {
                command = reader.readLine();
                if (command.equals("hello")) {
                    System.out.println("Hello there!");
                } else if (command.equals("quit")) {
                    return; // exit program
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unknown command.");
                }
            } while (true);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Java IO Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Basic input and output is all you need.

Specifically, [I/O from the Command Line](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html)

Answer (score 1):

A console program? You can read user input using [Console.readLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28%29). The Console class has a very detailed [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).